# Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are no longer permitted at /loader/0x55eae3bff1e8/aliased.pm line 1

Tags: perl

I run `cpanm` on Jenkins environment.

How to reproduce:

```
# cpanm -L local Carton
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are no longer permitted at /loader/0x55eae3bff1e8/aliased.pm line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /loader/0x55eae3bff1e8/App/cpanminus/script.pm line 1.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/perlbrew/bin/cpanm line 464.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/perlbrew/bin/cpanm line 464.
```

```
# cat /loader/0x55eae3bff1e8/App/cpanminus/script.pm
cat: /loader/0x55eae3bff1e8/App/cpanminus/script.pm: No such file or directory
```

Where did `/loader/0x55ea` come from and how to fix it?

Comment: Re "*Where did `/loader/0x55ea` come from*", A made up path to represent the location of virtual files provided by the `@INC` hook at address `0x55eae3bff1e`. It's a probably a file inlined in `cpanm`. /// Re "*how to fix it?*", Probably just a matter of updating your copy of `cpanm`.

Comment: @ikegami: You are right. I was sure that I did that. I installed fresh `cpanm`. Probably some error occur and I did not notice it. I reinstall again and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @ikegami: Probably `/@INC_hook/0xXXX` will be more meaningful. Where I can read about that? `https://perldoc.pl/search?q=%2Floader` finds noting ((

Comment: `require` in perlfunc (as directed by `@INC` in perlvar)